# C# Why SqlCommand constructor has both SqlConnection and SqlTransaction?

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, sqltransaction

While [SqlTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) has a **Connection** property, why does **SqlCommand** have a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/352y4sff(v=vs.110).aspx) with both SqlConnection and SqlTransaction?

Comment: I presume if you have multiple transactions, you might want to specify which one should be connected to the command.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio The question is: an `SqlTransaction` already has the `SqlConnection` inside, so why the `SqlCommand` can't have a constructor with only the `SqlTransaction` parameter?

Comment: @Jalil I was implying that you might execute a command on a different connection but fail the transaction on another connection if that command fails. But it's just an hypothesis.

Comment: Probably wrong by the look of `SqlCommand.ValidateCommand`. But I can't dig further now.